# Seat Post Compatibility

Tags: seatpost

I have a Kona Stinkey Deluxe and someone recently stole the seat post. I remember the seat post and it was called the RaceFace Evolve DH. Was wondering if there were any other types of seat posts that could work. Also not sure about the seat tube diameter so if someone could tell me what diameter it is that would be great as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any seat post can work to hold a saddle up.   The only two measurements that matter are

- outside diameter of the seatpost, so it clamps into the frame securely
- overall length of seatpost so it fits you - too short is bad, too long is not a big deal

The brand of the seat post is unimportant, but its quality and weight could be depending on how/where you ride.

Googling returns a 2018 model specs at https://konaworld.com/archive/2018/stinky_24.cfm

That says "SEATPOST Kona Thumb OB 31.6mm" so that vintage requires a 31.6mm diameter seat post.  No other size will fit unless you use shims and that's not needed here.

If your bike is a different year, then it could be a different size.

It is possible to measure the clamp in the bike frame, but the clamp has to have some play when open, so it may not read exactly right.   If you do this, use a vernier/digital caliper or even an internal micrometer, because a ruler  simply isn't good enough.

---

Other things for you to consider

- If your seatpost was a dropper then that gets a lot more expensive to replace.
- How will you stop this happening again?  A QR clamp is convenient, but provides little security.  Perhaps you should consider a nutted clamp, or store/park your bike somewhere more secure.
- You probably need a new saddle as well.

Comment: Another possibilty to prevent theft of a QR fastened seatpost & saddle is to take it along when you park your bike outside. (Something you see quite often in bigger cities.)

Comment: Actually there's a third very important measurement: setback. If you have a frame that had a seatpost with no integral head and a separate stamped steel head, it has a very short setback. If you then purchase a typical aluminum seatpost, chances are it has too long setback. The saddle is too far from the handlebars. You may be able to adjust the saddle forwards, but chances are it's at its extreme position, far outside the permitted limits that the arrows on the seat rails indicate. That's a recipe for cracked seat rails due to excessive forces on them.

Comment: @juhist: The 'Kona Stinkey Deluxe' is not the type of bike that has a Dutch or BSO-style straight seat-post with a separate stamped saddle clamp. Have a look at pictures in your favourite search engine.